# How to use self join to reshape duplicate rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, reshape, self-join

I have a duplicates rows and I want to concatenate them. They are like :

```
ID    Col1   Col2   Col3  ... Col46
-----------------------------------
id1    a1     b1     c1   ...  x1
id2    a2     b2     c2   ...  x2
id1    a1     b1     c1   ...  y1
id3    a3     b3     c3   ...  x3
id3    a3     b3     c3   ...  y3
id3    a3     b3     c3   ...  z3
```

and what I want to do is :

```
ID    Col1   Col2   Col3  ...  Col46   Col47   Col48
----------------------------------------------------
id1    a1     b1     c1   ...   x1      y1      None
id2    a2     b2     c2   ...   d2     None     None
id3    a3     b3     c3   ...   x3      y3       z3
```

for this, I'm using merge  :

```
  data_cliq = self.cliq.copy()
  self.cliq = pd.merge(self.cliq, data_cliq, on = 'ID', how = 'inner')
```

but I think I need something more complex than this because it doesn't give me the result that I wish.

Comment: Maybe take a look about `pivot` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first create `groups` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('ID')['Col46'].cumcount()

df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID','Col1','Col2','Col3'], 
                    columns='g', 
                    values='Col46', 
                    aggfunc=''.join).reset_index()

print (df)

g   ID Col1 Col2 Col3   0     1     2
0  id1   a1   b1   c1  x1    y1  None
1  id2   a2   b2   c2  x2  None  None
2  id3   a3   b3   c3  x3    y3    z3
```

And if need rename column names:

```
df['g'] = 'Col' + (df.groupby('ID')['Col46'].cumcount() + 46).astype(str)

df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID','Col1','Col2','Col3'], 
                    columns='g', 
                    values='Col46', 
                    aggfunc=''.join).reset_index()

print (df)
g   ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col46 Col47 Col48
0  id1   a1   b1   c1    x1    y1  None
1  id2   a2   b2   c2    x2  None  None
2  id3   a3   b3   c3    x3    y3    z3
```